# Invalid file: google-play-services_lib/build.xml in android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, ant, google-play-services

I have an android project in which i am trying to use services like maps etc., and so i came to know that i need to use `google-play-services_lib` library. So i just taken it from source sdk`(sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject)` folder and copied it to location `/Users/name/android/` on my computer. Now i imported the library in to eclipse. Next i created a reference to this library from eclipse like `MyApp->Properties->Android->Library Section/Add` and there are no errors in the project and working fine when i run it from `eclipse` but i just want to run it through terminal and here i moved to project location folder and tried the commands `ant clean` but received the following errors

```
Buildfile: /Users/name/android/project/project_name/build.xml

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /Users/name/andriod_installation/adt-bundle/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: Project_name
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-pre-clean:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/name/android/project/project_name/bin
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/name/android/project/project_name/gen
[getlibpath] Library dependencies:
[getlibpath] 
[getlibpath] ------------------
[getlibpath] Ordered libraries:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/name/andriod_installation/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:470: Invalid file: /Users/name/android/google-play-services_lib/build.xml

Total time: 1 second
```

Can anyone please let me know whats wrong with the `google_play_services_lib` or reference created to it, why ant was not able to find build.xml or saying invalid file ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here `ant` was failing to generate your build because Google no longer provides a build.xml for the Play library, we need to generate the build.xml in the Play library by running the below command

```
android update lib-project --path <playlib_path>
```

Now we need to clean both `google_play_services_lib` and `your_project` in eclipse

Comment: I was using my own library project. So, I executed the above command by specifying the my libary project path with target api level

Comment: This worked, although `android` required to specify a target, like `--target "Google Inc.:Google APIs:22"`.